# opening vs2010 solution with vs2012 without changing sln

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

I'm trying Visual Studio 2012. I can open VS2010 solutions with VS2012` which is fine and expected, but what I wonder is if we can open VS2010 solutions without changing them. I want this because we use a source control system and some members of our team still use VS2010, so I don't want my solution file changed.

Comment: Yes, surely you can. Just 'Reject'/'Cancel'/'No' when it prompts/offers you to upgrade the .sln to 4.5 & it should work perfectly as it is with previous versions of VS.  use .NET 2.0 on VS 2010 without any hassles... :)

Comment: When I open solution, it does not prompt me about these changes you describe. Is there any setting which enables these features?

Comment: I forgot to mention what VS2012 did. When I clicked the sln and selected open with vs2012 from the context menu, vs2012 directly migrated my sln and csprojs to 2012 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike previous versions of Visual Studio, I don't *think* that VS2012 makes any change to VS2010 solution files at all when you open them. That's why there's no prompt.

The simplest thing is just to open the solutions as an experiment - maybe make some change that you'd normally want to make, e.g. adding a new project - and then diff your file to the one in source control. I'd expect it to be fine. When you've finished your experiment, just revert your local changes either way (assuming they're not changes you want to actually keep), and you'll be away.

Comment: It is a little weird this time. I tried to open sln with VS2012 twice. At first VS2012 directly migrated my sln and proj files without prompting and opened migration report. At my second try, some of the csproj files changed and It says "Visual Studio has made non-functional changes to this project in order to enable the project to open in this version and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without impacting project behavior." And some of my csproj files, setting.designer files changed. Will these changes cause problems when the solution is opened with VS2010. Actually I am a bit afraid of using VS2012.

Comment: I tried to add new projects from 10 to 12 and 12 to 10. It seems ok. Thanks for help.